# Loading Image from URL in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to load images from urls using Glide Library, but no image is showing in the imageview, then I tried to load it using Picasso Library, but same issue.
But image is loading properly from drawable folder using R.drawable.image

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryGridAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final CategoryGridModel categoryGridModel = categoryGridModels.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(categoryGridModel.getDescription ());
        holder.frameLayout.setBackgroundColor (Color.parseColor (categoryGridModel.getColor ()));
        holder.imageView.setImageResource (R.drawable.ic_icon_archary);
        // Glide.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(holder.imageView);
//        Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(holder.imageView);

//        Glide.with(context)
//                .asBitmap()
//                .load(categoryGridModel.getImageUrl())
//                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_icon_football)
//                .dontAnimate()
//                .into(holder.imageView);
//                 Log.d ("IMAGE URL",categoryGridModel.getImageUrl () );

        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, categoryGridModel.getImageUrl (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Make sure that you have the `INTERNET` permission in your manifest, and change your URLs to use `https` instead; e.g., `https://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png`.

Comment: i tried both of your suggestions, but still same issue

Comment: Are you sure you have the permission spelled exactly correctly? You might have a look at [your logs](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat#running) for anything relevant.

Comment: Try your approach but removing the asBitmap... the asBitmap is good when you implement the into CustomTarget<Bitmap>() but here I think is not necessary.

Comment: @ManuelMato That code is commented. I am trying with Glide.with(context).load("https://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(holder.imageView); now

Comment: Then It´s really weird because your first glide code it is ok so if with glide and piccasso doesn´t work, then the problem isn´t in the image loader.., and i don´t know where... try to populate in the holder only the imageView, check that has width and height defined, match parent or another, but no wrap content... if it works, then is necessary to search in another code place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible fixes for this problem are:

1. replace the glide with() param with holder.imageView.
2. Enable clearTextTraffic in Manifest or add a network config file.
3. remove `dontAnimate()` in Glide.

Comment: Replace `Glide.with(context)` with `Glide.with(holder.imageView)`

Comment: According to the Glide documentation, You need to pass a View/activity/fragment in `.with()` https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/Glide.html#with-android.app.Fragment-

Comment: Passing a `Context` is fine, too. Are you sure your `context` isn't null in `onBindViewHolder()`, @RanjitSinghShekhawat?

Comment: Please check full Adapter code.  https://codeshare.io/5owLQp

Comment: @RanjitSinghShekhawat Hmm, interesting. That's all good. Well, I haven't actually used Glide in a while, so I'm probably missing/forgetting something.

Comment: No problem @MikeM. Prathamesh bro your suggestion worked for me when I pass single URL, but when I pass array of urls, it is still same issue. could you please see the complete adapter code. https://codeshare.io/5owLQp